OpenCV findContours() only draws round area around object, doesn't detect actual contour
I am trying to create an automatic instance segmentation dataset generator using Unity and OpenCV for Unity. Basically, the app takes pictures of objects at different angles and lighting situations and exports them automatically. In a separate pass, I export only the mask of the object, so findCountours() (theoretically) has an easier time finding the contours of the object, here is what the mask images look like:


I want to to use findContours() to export the normalized coordinates of the object outlines. I want to train a YOLO-model with the data later. The problem is that the contour looks nothing like what I expect it to look like.

I have tried multiple approaches, like different modes or just using python to extract the contours, nothing helps. I'm starting to think that the problem has something to do with the images themselves, does anyone have an idea what my issue might be here? This is the function that uses findContours().
void ProcessMaskImage(Mat maskImage, string fileName)
{
Mat gray = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(maskImage, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new List<MatOfPoint>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
        foreach (MatOfPoint contour in contours)
        {
            List<Vector2> normalizedContour = new List<Vector2>();
            foreach (Point point in contour.toArray())
            {
                float x = (float)point.x / gray.width();
                float y = (float)point.y / gray.height();
                normalizedContour.Add(new Vector2(x, y));
            }
    
            sb.Append($"0 "); // Replace 0 with the actual class ID later
            foreach (Vector2 point in normalizedContour)
            {
                sb.Append($"{point.x.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} {point.y.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)} ");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }
    
        SaveYOLOFormat(sb.ToString(), fileName);
    }

Here is the python code I also tried if that helps:
def convert_mask_to_yolo(mask_image_path, output_path, class_id=0):
    mask = cv2.imread(mask_image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    height, width = mask.shape

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    yolo_format = ""
    for contour in contours:
        normalized_contour = []
        for point in contour:
            x = point[0][0] / width
            y = point[0][1] / height
            normalized_contour.append((x, y))
        
        yolo_format += f"{class_id} " + " ".join([f"{x} {y}" for x, y in normalized_contour]) + "\n"

    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(mask_image_path))[0] + '.txt'
    with open(os.path.join(output_path, file_name), 'w') as file:
        file.write(yolo_format)


Your mask is not pure black and white. If you threshold at 0 you get the oval. If you use otsu thresholding, you get your proper figure. So do a proper otsu threshold after converting to grayscale and before getting contours.

the thing glows. https://i.sstatic.net/E3x1zsZP.png why? you have full control over the rendering. just draw the model with untextured white triangles, and nothing else.

Continued from above: Read the findContours docs. It says "Source, an 8-bit single-channel image. Non-zero pixels are treated as 1's. Zero pixels remain 0's, so the image is treated as binary". See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gae4156f04053c44f886e387cff0ef6e08.  So not thresholding properly is like thresholding at 0, which produces your oval, since your grayscale image has very dark, but not pure black in the oval around it.

@fmw42 thank you very much, this worked for me :)
